# How can I check that a collection in Firestore already exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm creating a user and a document that corresponds to the user. I can successfully create a document with all the things I want inside it on user signup, my problem arrises when trying to verify whether the document already exists inside the collection.

```
  const userRef = doc(db, 'user', user.uid);
  const snapshot = await userRef.get();
  
  const {email} = user;
  const {displayName} = data;
  
  if(!snapshot.exists) {
    setDoc( doc(db, `user`, user.uid), {
      displayName,
      email,
      createdAt: new Date() 
    })
  }
```

The problem happens when calling the `.get()` on userRef. It returns this error:

`TypeError: userRef.get is not a function`.

I'm sure I'm missing something.

FYI: replacing `!snapshot.exists` with `true` it creates the document in the collection.

Comment: if the second line throws an error, I don't really get how your script can go after it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getDoc()` as follows. Don’t forget to import it as well.

```
const snapshot = await getDoc(userRef);
```

Doing `userRef.get();` is JS SDK V8 syntax.

---

In addition, Note that with the JS SDK V9, [`exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentsnapshot#documentsnapshotexists) is now a method and not a property. So you should adapt your code as follows:

```
if(!snapshot.exists()) {
   // ... 
}
```

Comment: Oh! ok good to know! Problem still unfortunately persists. Am I using the doc import wrong?

Comment: "Am I using the doc import wrong?" Maybe, I cannot say if I don't see the import code.

Comment: import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";  is all I do beforehand